# Debian 8: installation step failed - Select and install software

Tags: linux, debian, ssd, virtual-machine, parallels

I'm installing the Debian 8 with Parallels VM in the MacBook Pro. I recently upgraded to a new SSD (750 GB) and the configuration is provided below,

```
  Untitled:

  Available:    579.07 GB (579,070,930,944 bytes)
  Capacity: 751.07 GB (751,068,229,632 bytes)
  Mount Point:  /
  File System:  APFS
  Writable: Yes
  Ignore Ownership: No
  BSD Name: disk1s1
  Volume UUID:  53A0D82B-1F22-47C4-8330-410523F02D49
  Physical Drive:
  Device Name:  APPLE SSD SM768E
  Media Name:   AppleAPFSMedia
  Medium Type:  SSD
  Protocol: SATA
  Internal: Yes
  Partition Map Type:   Unknown
```

I have selected the `Desktop environment`, `Print server` and `Standard utilities`. I took about 3 hours and I finally get the message that the installation is not successful and I can try again.

what is the issue here and will it somehow related to the new SSD or corrupted iso file ?

Some guidance for the walk-through of the situation will also be helpful.

Comment: To debug this, you're going to have to provide the installation logs. Provide relevant parts of `/var/log/syslog` (https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/i386/ch05s04.html)

Comment: How do I get the log?

Comment: @mtak do you know how can I get the earlier version like 8.7 iso file? It seems not in the Debian website.

Comment: One Google query away: https://cdimage.debian.org/mirror/cdimage/archive/

Comment: I went to the page earlier but they seems offer in different file format. How do I download the iso actually? Like in the page, they have the 8.7 version that I would like to try away, https://cdimage.debian.org/mirror/cdimage/archive/